# How to control volume in Deezer for iOS

Tags: ios, deezer

Using [Deezer's iOS SDK](http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/ios), I need to control the **playback volume** dynamically, do some fade-ins and fade-outs. The music is mixed with other audio sources, so the volume control must remain specific for each source.

The problem is, I don't see anything about volume control in the iOS SDK...

Any suggestion welcome!